# change Images src with event onClick window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onclick

as soon as you click on the picture, the picture will be swapped and a new window will open automatically on https://stackoverflow.com/. Any ideas/support what i have missed that this combination would work?
Currently the picture is swapping, unfortunately the new window doesn't open.

```js
document.getElementById("img").onclick = function() {
    if(this.src == "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"){
        this.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
    } else {
        this.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg";
    }
};
```

```html
       
<a href="##"onClick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank','width=900,height=880, toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=no'), BoldText(this);"><img id="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" height="22" width="22" alt="Twitter"></a>
```

Comment: Get rid of BoldText and it does work. I would suggest putting it into a JavaScript expression instead of inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new window isn't opening because it's being blocked be either the browser or an ad-block extension! Try disabling your ad-block extension if you have any and allowing pop-ups in your browser settings for your page!

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with the img swapping and opening up in new window.
Your `_blank` should cover the new window.

From jsfiddle I have it working: https://jsfiddle.net/xg1w7b6o/

What browser are you using? Maybe its browser specific that the window is not opening.

Comment: Thank you, so much i rechecked and now it works, on this time it did not work. maybe i had an issue with my cache.. sorry for that and thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help